# copy function in class definition in python

Tags: python

Im doing a class for polynomial and i have a problem with a copy function. It suppose to create a copy of the Poly object and return a reference to the new Poly object. Im really stuck on this copy idea. Thanks for any help

```
class Poly:

    def __init__ (self, p):
        self.a = p
        self.deg= len(p) -1
        if len(p) == 1 and p[0] == 0:
            self.deg = -1

    def evalPoly(self,x0):
        ''' evaluates the polynomial at value x'''
        b=0
        for coefficients in reversed(self.a):
            b=b*x0+int(coefficients)
        return b

    def polyPrime(self):
        '''replaces the coeffiecients of self with the coefficients           
        of the derivative polynomial '''
        if self.deg == 0:
            return np.zeroes(1,float), 0
        else:
            newdeg=self.deg-1
            p=[i*self.a[i] for i in range(1,self.deg+1)]
            p=str(p)[1: -1]
            p=eval(p)
        return p

    def copy(self):
        return Poly(self.a)
```

I'm stuck on how to create a copy of the Poly object and return a reference to the new Poly object

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're stuck on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that as `self.a` is a list then you are passing a reference to that list in the instantiation of the new Poly object.

You should copy the list and give that copy to instantiate the object:

```
import copy

class Poly:
    ...
    def copy(self):
        return Poly(copy.copy(self.a))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually hiding up in `__init__()`.

```
    self.a = p[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

Check out copy module:

http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate why it doesn't work? This works perfectly for me:

```
class Poly(object):

    def __init__ (self, p):
        self.a = p
        self.deg= len(p) -1
        if len(p) == 1 and p[0] == 0:
            self.deg = -1

    def evalPoly(self,x0):
        ''' evaluates the polynomial at value x'''
        b=0
        for coefficients in reversed(self.a):
            b=b*x0+int(coefficients)
        return b

    def polyPrime(self):
        '''replaces the coeffiecients of self with the coefficients           
        of the derivative polynomial '''
        if self.deg == 0:
            return np.zeroes(1,float), 0
        else:
            newdeg=self.deg-1
            p=[i*self.a[i] for i in range(1,self.deg+1)]
            p=str(p)[1: -1]
            p=eval(p)
        return p

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.a, self.deg)

    def copy(self):
        return Poly(self.a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Poly((1,3))
    print p
    x = p.copy()
    print x
```

Edit: Okay I see now he was passing in a list which was mutable is the general consensus.